# Unloading different sets of projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

Is there an extension to Visual Studio that provides the ability to create something like an 'unloaded project profile' for a solution?

I have a solution with a large number of projects (~100). When working on a certain part, I can unload unrelated projects to improve performance. I'd like to be able to save this group of unloaded projects, so that when I switch to working on a different part I can then cause it's projects to be loaded instead.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but just get a new computer perhaps? Hardware is much cheaper than developer time; I have a visual studio solution with >100 projects that loads in less than 10 seconds because it's off an SSD.

Comment: Oh, I have a decent dev box, and 2012 is certainly better at handling lots of projects compared to 2010 - but it still makes a difference if VS (and addins like ReSharper) only have to look at a limited subset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load/unload multiple projects in a solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956803/how-to-load-unload-multiple-projects-in-a-solution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up writing my own extension to do this - [Loaded Projects](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c0b75ba-0f56-4809-b0b6-409f777982de), for Visual Studio 2012.

But then I discovered [Funnel](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5396fa4a-d638-471b-ac3d-671ccd2ea369) (by Dimitri Dering), which takes the same concept to the next level, with a more polished UI and additional features.

Comment: Great find. Funnel is awesome.

Comment: see my answer below about the new feature in VS 2019 for doing this with "Solution Filter Files"

Comment: Fwiw, "_WARNING: The development of this extension is discontinued. The VS 2017 API interface used by vsFunnel for filtering projects at load time is no longer supported by Microsoft._" Appears it might still work with some bearable weirdness on VS 2017 and earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2019 has a new concept called "Solution Filter Files".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019

You can right click on a solution after you've unloaded what you want and do "Save as solution filter".  It creates a file which is a list of projects to INCLUDE in opening.
So if a new project is added, I don't think it would be picked up.

Another important feature to note is the right click "Show unloaded projects" and the right click "Hide unloaded projects".

FYI - The file looks like this:

```
{
  "solution": {
    "path": "IvaraDotNet.sln",
    "projects": [
      "AssetManagement\\StaticLoad\\AssetManagementStaticLoad.vcxproj",
       ....
      "framework\\oqpersman\\oqpersman.vcxproj"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019#solution-filter-files) on the feature.

Answer (score 2):

This guy recommends comparmentalizing projects into "Solution Folders" so you can right-click and load/unload all of the projects in a given solution folder:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/03/06/large-visual-studio-solutions-by-loading-unloading-projects.aspx

He also shows how you can write macros to load or unload groups of projects:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/03/11/visual-studio-macros-for-unloading-reloading-projects.aspx