# How to load/unload multiple projects in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

We have around 50 projects in our solution and that's a big time drain. The load/unload project feature is great help but the process is slow and tedious since there is so many projects and many dependencies between them.

I would like to have project 'templates' or 'presets'. For example, I want to work on project D and that means that projects A, B and C have to be loaded and everything else unloaded. If I want to work on project W that means that all projects from A to W have to be loaded.

Is this possible? The active 'template' would usually change few times per day.

Comment: cant you make multiple solutions? one for A, B and so on..

Comment: How? We use team foundation server for source control. All projects are a part of one solution (product) and we need project references.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unloading different sets of projects in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261245/unloading-different-sets-of-projects-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have at least three options:

- Use Solution Folders. These allow you to unload/reload projects in a group. Just create a Solution Folder, move a few projects there, and use the 'Unload Projects in Solution Folder' context menu item.
- Use Macros. There are [examples](https://www.technologytoolbox.com/blog/jjameson/archive/2009/03/11/visual-studio-macros-for-unloading-reloading-projects.aspx) that do exactly that.
- [Hacky/Speculation] The unloaded projects list is stored in the `.suo` file, so it might be convenient to create several .suo files and switch between the configurations by overwriting the original one.

[Here is the original blog post](https://www.technologytoolbox.com/blog/jjameson/archive/2009/03/06/large-visual-studio-solutions-by-loading-unloading-projects.aspx) from an ex-Microsoft employee having the same issues and solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2019 has a new concept called "Solution Filter Files".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019

You can right click on a solution after you've unloaded what you want and do "Save as solution filter". It creates a file which is a list of projects to INCLUDE in opening. So if a new project is added, I don't think it would be picked up.

Another important feature to note is the right click "Show unloaded projects" and the right click "Hide unloaded projects".

FYI - The file looks like this:

```js
{
  "solution": {
    "path": "IvaraDotNet.sln",
    "projects": [
      "AssetManagement\\StaticLoad\\AssetManagementStaticLoad.vcxproj",
       ....
      "framework\\oqpersman\\oqpersman.vcxproj"
    ]
  }
}
```